# sorting cells of each rows using libre office

Tags: sorting, rows, libreoffice, cells

I have a sheet with 240*4 data (rows  and columns). I want to sort cells of each rows randomly. For example if the orginal libre office sheet is as  below:

```
 aaa   bbb  ccc dddd
 fff   hhh  kkk llll
 ccc   bbb  ggg pppp
```

I would like to get:

```
bbb aaa ddd ccc
kkk hhh fff lll
ggg ccc ppp bbb
```

I found lots of solutions about how to sort full rows (the row number 1 with 3 or 2 ) but I did not find anything about how I can sort the cells in each row using libra office. Could you please help me?

Best

Answer (score 0):

I think that the LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc extension Permutate! will help you. Download and install from https://sourceforge.net/projects/permutate/